# Why does Swift constructor use named parameter calling?

Tags: swift

Swift Programming Language's example code does not call super.init in the first line.  It would seem that's an unsafe practice as an inherited item can be overridden by parent constructor, right?

```
class EquilateralTriangle: NamedShape {
    var sideLength: Double = 0.0

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 3
    }

    var perimeter: Double {
    get {
        return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
    set {
        sideLength = newValue / 3.0
    }
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "An equilateral triagle with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. in that case the `sideLenght` will be overridden with its default value, and you will lose the user's input. you can read more about the _initlaization_ procedure here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html

Comment: @holex `sideLength` will *not* be overridden with its default value. Specifying a default value is not required in this case but may come in handy when you have multiple initializers of which some don't require `sideLength` to be known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In initializers you have to fully prepare the object before calling `super.init()`. That means that all properties declared by the subclass need to have a value by the time you call the super implementation of the initializer.

After calling `super.init()` you may overwrite properties inherited from the superclass. `numberOfSides` is an inherited property and because of that it's overwritten *after* calling the super implementation.
`numberOfSides =` and `self.numberOfSides =` are equivalent in this example.

To put things short:
1. Properties declared by the subclass must be set before calling `super.init()`
2. Inherited properties must be overwritten after calling `super.init()`

The compiler will throw an error for the first case, but I'm not sure about the latter.

Comment: This seems wrong because a child class should not be required to know what goes in the parent.  So the fact that parent can override child properties seems counterintuitive.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, sorry. The parent can't overwrite child properties. What are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry I misread your point 1 - "properties declared by the subclass must be set before calling super.init".  What's the rationale behind having to prep all subclass properties first before super.init?

Comment: @FabianKreiser, that is not quite true as you have written here. this documentation says something different about the initialisation procedure: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html where did you get step 1. from?

Comment: In *"Two-Phase Initialization"* it says that phase one goes the chain up and phase two goes the chain down.